# How to access same name table fields in table join using db_fetch_object

Tags: 6, database

I've SNO in both A and B tables.

I do

```
db_query('SELECT * from A JOIN B on A.SNO=B.SNO')
```

Now how do I access both SNO fields of A and B using db_fetch_object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name your fields in the SELECT, then you can use AS to rename them to something clearer:

```
SELECT fielda, fieldb, A.SNO AS thisone, B.SNO AS thatone, FROM... etc
```

Comment: I've 15 fields and I'm using SELECT *. I can't use offsets as one addition/deletion of a field will break the offsets. Renaming fields is the only way to do? What's the pros & cons of renaming the fields?

Comment: If you can't using numeric fetch, SELECT field AS alias is your only option and you need to do this explicitly for all fields.